# Errors on formulas with Input value of 0.000

Tags: formula

I am a beginner to crystal and am using Crystal 2020.   How can I use formulas for sum, average if my value can include 0.000?   I have 2 or 4 different values that get used to perform the functions and get accurate results as long as the value is not 0.

My formula works as long as my value does not include 0

```
    IF (not(isnull({Alcohol.Result1})) and
isnull({Alcohol.Result2})) then
{Alcohol.Result1}
else 

    IF (not(isnull({Alcohol.Result1})) and
not(isnull({Alcohol.Result2}))) then
{Alcohol.Result1} + {Alcohol.Result2}
```

Comment: What "errors" ... And what "value". Why wouldn't the above formulas not work if `Alcohol.Result1 == 0` or `Alcohol.Result2 == 0`? And you may have a misunderstanding in what `isnull` does. It doesn't check for `0` or `0.00` (ie a value of "zero") but check if there is a missing value/empty cell.